# customize Spring MVC requestBody mapping based on HTTP method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

My Java 8, Spring boot 1.4 application has a controller method consuming application/json (jackson 2.6.5) as

```
public MyModel updateModel(@Valid @RequestBody( required = true) MyModel myModel) {
....
}
```

And within MyModel, I have a field that I want to given auto-generated value when HTTP method = POST, directly use request value  when HTTP method = PUT. IS it doable?

Hope I explain it well. Any helps are deeply appreciated

Comment: many thanks for all the helps, comments. Really appreciated. I have removed the read-only jackson annotation from my DTO and moved the data auto-generation logic for that field to service, which I think making more sense conceptually too

Answer (score 1):

Add an `HttpServletRequest` parameter and call `getMethod()`.

See [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods) for supported method argument types. Or **read the javadoc** of [`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

You should also specify the HTTP Methods you want your controller method to handle, e.g. `@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})`

Comment: oh. I see. can I do it with 2 controller methods? 1 for POST, 1 for PUT. That looks clearer to me. Even though, how can I pass the method to the setter of that field in MyModel, which is just a POJO with jackson annotations

Comment: You can't. That is something you have to do in the controller method.

Comment: but when my controller gets MyModel, it is already mapped. I will not be able to know if the field is auto-created or set by payload

Comment: No idea what your problem is. If method is PUT, the particular field of the data object was assigned from request. If method is POST, the field was not assigned, and your controller code can do the auto-assigning, before doing whatever action was requested on the object (create/update/...).

Comment: In the case of POST (create), I need to ignore the input of this field and take an auto-generated value; but with PUT, I need to compare the value of this field in the request (if it is present) with a path variable

Comment: Again, sounds like things your *controller* should be doing, but I'm curious: If the value is auto-generated for POST, why would the value be in the request data? And if the value should come from a path variable for PUT, why would the value be in the request data? In short, why would the value be in the request data at all? And if it is, why do you care, since your controller will just be replacing it in both cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138656/discussion-between-gigi2-and-andreas).